# AKS with Application gateway ingress controller configuration

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I configured application gateway ingress controller for my Kubernetes cluster, but I can't access my pod container app named *myapp* running on port 8080/TCP.

I created a service that has the following configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      name: myapp-api
```

and the ingress with the following configuration:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: myapp-service
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: Exact
```

but still every time I access the fronted IP of the application gateway, I get 502 Bad Gateway? Am I missing something?

[image: AGIC Error]

Comment: Did you check service health from application gateway ? 502 errors pointing out that service is not healthy or connection issues

Comment: Hi, yes that was the issue, I solved it by adding the correct annotation, the container returned 404 (expected code) but application gateway saw as unhealthy and returned 502, to fix the issue I added the following annotation to the ingress: appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-status-codes: "200 -399, 404 "

Comment: Here are the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/create-k8s-cluster-with-aks-applicationgateway-ingress) and [Application Gateway document](https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/tutorials/tutorial.general/) tutorial-related discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Glad @[**Razvan**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18733784/razvan) that you resolved the issue yourself. Posting your resolution as an answer to help other community members.

There can be many reasons for **App Gateway 502** errors mainly if the backend health shows as **unhealthy** in Application Gateway.

> That you resolved using the correct annotation which in turn returned the **404 Error**.
> It is resolved by adding the following annotation to the ingress: `appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-status-codes: "200 -399, 404 "`

After adding the **health probes**, the **backend service** will become **healthy**.

There is a similar issue on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/739844/azure-application-gateway-giving-bad-gateway-502-1.html), where the **502 Bad Gateway error** on Azure Applicate Gateway Ingress is **solved** by **Ingress Annotations** as well as the Probes Path correctly and also few reasons mentioned here which causes this error.